# Using PowerShell variable in line

Tags: powershell, variables

I would like to set a variable to be used inline as below but it does not behave as I anticipated. Ultimately the command that works that I would like it to run, just use a variable to set it, is

```
'$Version = 'v14,11.253.0'.replace(",",".").replace("v","")' to get a output of '14.11.253.0'
```

Why does this not work?

```
$Replace = '.replace(",",".").replace("v","")'
$Version = 'v14,11.253.0'$Replace
$Version
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment, here's how you might use a Function to make this code more repeatable:

```
Function FixVersion ($version) { $version  -replace ',','.' -replace 'v' }

$Version = FixVersion 'v14,11.253.0'
```

You could also take this a little further (and perhaps make it more usable) by having the function accept pipeline input so that you can use it like this:

```
Function FixVersion { 
    Param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $Version
    )
    $Version  -replace ',','.' -replace 'v'
 }

$Version = 'v14,11.253.0' | FixVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
$Version = 'v14,11.253.0' -replace ',','.' -replace 'v'
```

Not sure why you're trying to store the replace methods in a string variable, but it won't behave as you're expecting, because it's a string.

Comment: I need to change multiple lines of code with different 'replace' commands so i would like to change it in one location (i.e. set variable) so I can use it over and over again and not have to constantly be changing dozens of lines of code.

Comment: It sounds like you should create a function.